# Click and show more element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show more when you click on the div `ShowMore` but when I do it all section show more and not the element where I just click .

In summary when you click on the div `.showMore`, div  `.panel` increases in height to show hidden text . But when I click on the `.showMore` every div with the class `.panel` also animate while I am only the clicked div animate height

I guess that is a small line of code that I miss

**JS**

```
$(".showMore").click(function (){
if ($(".panel").height() == 100) {
    $(this).css({transform:"rotate(90deg)"});
$(".panel").animate({height: "250px"});
}
else if ($(".panel").height() == 250) {
    $(this).css({transform:"rotate(0deg)"});
    $(".panel").animate({height: "100px"});
}
});
```

[Full code here: Codepen](http://codepen.io/Pierreszwk/pen/ZOmqNb)

Comment: You should use ID to determine which panel to expand

Comment: i can't use class ?

Comment: If you are using a class, every occurrence of you class will be expanded. If you use a specific ID, only this one will be expanded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find element with class `panel` that contains clicked element:

```
$(".showMore").click(function (){

  var panel = $(this).closest(".panel");

  if (panel.height() == 100) {
    $(this).css({transform:"rotate(90deg)"});
    panel.animate({height: "250px"});
  }
  else if (panel.height() == 250) {
    $(this).css({transform:"rotate(0deg)"});
    panel.animate({height: "100px"});
  }
});
```

Note: get rid of duplicate `id`s in your html.

Comment: when you write "panel.animate" , js know we talk about the class ".panel" ?

Comment: @Pierreszwk - variable `panel` in the code above is a jQuery object that wraps DOM element with class `panel`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make use of `$(this)` a bit more by accessing it's parent element.

```
    //alert('ok');
    $(".showMore").click(function (){
    if ($(".panel").height() == 100) {
        $(this).css({transform:"rotate(90deg)"});
    $(this).parent(".panel").animate({height: "250px"});
    }
    else if ($(this > ".panel").height() == 250) {
        $(this).css({transform:"rotate(0deg)"});
        $(this).parent(".panel").animate({height: "100px"});
    }
```

Comment: I'm just reading '.parent()' method on jQuery ! Thank's a lot ;)

Comment: No problem. If you think this answered your question please mark it as an accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".showMore").click(function (){
    var height=$(this).parent().height();
    if (height == 100) {
        $(this).css({transform:"rotate(90deg)"});
    $(this).parent().animate({height: "250px"});
    }
    else if (height == 250) {
        $(this).css({transform:"rotate(0deg)"});
        $(this).parent().animate({height: "100px"});
    } 
});
```

http://codepen.io/beshoysemsem/pen/xOQmRQ